# BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE is missing after update to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a multi modular app and for some reason VERSION_CODE generated field has disappeared from all modules except the root one, I have tested it on one more project and it behaves the same. Right now I have simply downgraded to 4.0.1, but thats just a workaround.

I need to restore BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE in all modules using gradle tools 4.1.0

Would appreciate any help.

defaultConfig example:

```
buildFeatures {
    buildConfig = true
}

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion global["androidMinSdkVersion"]
    targetSdkVersion global["androidTargetSdkVersion"]

    versionCode global["versionString"]

    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath true
        }
    }
}
```

Here comes the BuildConfig code on 4.0.1

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "app";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "flavour";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 107;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "6.0.0";
  // Field from build type: debug
  public static final String AMQP_URL = "url";
  // Field from build type: debug
  public static final String API_VERSION_SUFFIX = "V_04_04_09";
  // Field from build type: debug
  public static final String BASE_URL = "url";
  // Field from product flavor: flavour
  public static final String BUILD_FLAVOR = "flavour";
  // Field from build type: debug
  public static final int DB_VERSION = 53;
}
```

And here is 4.1.0

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "app";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "flavour";
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "6.0.0";
  // Field from build type: debug
  public static final String AMQP_URL = "url";
  // Field from build type: debug
  public static final String API_VERSION_SUFFIX = "V_04_04_09";
  // Field from build type: debug
  public static final String BASE_URL = "url";
  // Field from product flavor: flavour
  public static final String BUILD_FLAVOR = "flavour";
  // Field from build type: debug
  public static final int DB_VERSION = 53;
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> I have a multi modular app and for some reason VERSION_CODE generated field has disappeared from all modules except the root one

That appears to be related to [this reported issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158695880). In that case, it was `VERSION_NAME` that was missing from library modules. See [this specific comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158695880) for their rationale. <strike>Apparently, they fixed `VERSION_NAME` but did not fix `VERSION_CODE`.</strike> When I test this, I do not get either `VERSION_NAME` or `VERSION_CODE`, so I cannot explain how your module gets `VERSION_NAME`.

You should be able to switch to [using `buildConfigField`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips) to supply your version code:

```
 buildConfigField "long", "VERSION_CODE", global["versionString"]
```

Comment: Sadly bit no, it is not working too, I think it conflicts with default VERSION_CODE, but I believe I can fix this by adding something like VERSION_CODE1. I will try it.

Comment: @Void: That possibility occurred to me when I was writing the answer, but I assumed/hoped that Google would not both block the use of `VERSION_CODE` and fail to supply their own value. :-( There *really* should not be a problem with your own custom name for the field. Just, um, don't take after your SO handle and declare it as type `Void`. :-)

Comment: So what I ended up with is this:

buildConfigField "int", "VERSION_CODE1", String.valueOf(global["versionString"])

It works just fine, hope I will migrate back to default field after it will be fixed

Comment: not working for this fonction : the versionname is Null and a lot of another fields of package info.

 public static String getApplicationVersionName(Context pContext) {

        String version = "0";

        try {
            PackageInfo pInfo = pContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pContext.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            version = pInfo.versionName;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            printStackTrace(e);
        }
        return version;
    }

Comment: @SalimLachdhaf: Sorry, but your code snippet seems to have nothing to do with this question.

Comment: updating to 4.1.0 caused this issue, the BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE, and either packageInfo most attributes are null ! , for this i posted the snippet code (get versionName and versionCode form packageInfo)

Comment: I get this error when trying your suggestion: Could not get unknown property 'global' for DefaultConfig_decorated.

Answer (score 70):

add `buildConfigField` to `buildTypes` in module build.gradle file

```
buildConfigField("long", "VERSION_CODE", "${defaultConfig.versionCode}")        
buildConfigField("String","VERSION_NAME","\"${defaultConfig.versionName}\"")
```

example,

```
buildTypes {
    debug{
        buildConfigField("long", "VERSION_CODE", "${defaultConfig.versionCode}")
        buildConfigField("String","VERSION_NAME","\"${defaultConfig.versionName}\"")

        //..
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField("long", "VERSION_CODE", "${defaultConfig.versionCode}")
        buildConfigField("String","VERSION_NAME","\"${defaultConfig.versionName}\"")

        //...
    }
}
```

the `defaultConfig.versionCode` and `defaultConfig.versionName` value is

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    //..
}
```

in your module build.gradle

you can create field in `BuildConfig` by writing `buildConfigField` method in module build.gradle. The method first parameter is create field type, second is field name, third is value.

Android Studio 4.1

Comment: and how to access VERSION_NAME in classes?

Comment: @RahulPawar apply `gradle changes` in project and just write `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` in your source code. reference : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips?hl=en#simplify-app-development

Comment: hmm I tried a variant of this solution but with a long variable for code and string for name defined in the project build.gradle ext block, and I got some garbage error about method signature something or other doesn't exist.  When I tried exactly your approach, everything worked!  Gradle, you are responsible for too many of my gray hairs :\

Comment: It's getting NULL now.

Comment: This seems to work, but why is it needed, if defaultConfig already has it?

Comment: `VERSION_CODE` should be `int` not `long`

Answer (score 13):

We also have a multi-module setup and we were able to workaround with minimal changes by adding the following lines to every module's `build.gradle`

```
buildConfigField 'int', 'VERSION_CODE', "${rootProject.appVersionCode}"
buildConfigField 'String', 'VERSION_NAME', "\"${rootProject.appVersionName}\""
```

Comment: Thanks, I have put this on my build.gradle inside defaultConfig:

buildConfigField 'int', 'VERSION_CODE', "${versionCode}"
buildConfigField 'String', 'VERSION_NAME', "\"${versionName}\""

Answer (score 5):

You can use the other answers here as a workaround, but this answer is just to inform you of the official reply from the people working on the bug. This will not be fixed as it is an intended behaviour.

Here's what the Google engineers say:

> Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior) Hi all,
>
> Yes, we should have deprecated this first. Since this happened
> (several months ago), we have put in place better policies for
> deprecation/removal of properties. This happened kind of late for 4.1
> though, and this particular issue fell through the cracks so we did
> not get a chance to decide whether to revert this change (and we even
> missed putting this change in the release notes at first). We
> apologize for this.
>
> Some of the motivation behind this were to reduce/remove the confusion
> around 2 points:
>
> Users accessing the BuildConfig fields but not setting them in the
> DSL. This would definitively be broken and not do what one would
> expect (ie these are static values, and won't magically reflect the
> version of the app the library is embedded in) The library
> AndroidManifest.xml file contains the values set in the DSL, but these
> values are completely ignored by the consuming app(s) during manifest
> merging (they are also overridden) If you want to keep injecting the
> values from a common place into all your library project's BuildConfig
> fields, you could continue to do this manually with your own custom
> fields. These fields will only exist if you set them via the DSL
> (therefore preventing problem #1 above), and will not impact the
> library manifest (problem #2 above).
>
> However, if you have a large setup with many library projects, this
> pattern will generate a lot of duplicates. It would make more sense to
> have a single module that generates a similar class, and have all your
> library projects (or at least the ones that need the info) depend on
> it.

Answer (score 3):

You can access variables via your package name + BuildConfig + Variable.

example: `com.heregoesyourpackagename.BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE`

this will return the value placed in the Build gradle

Answer (score 3):

My issue fixed after adding line in build gradle app module

```
android {
buildFeatures {
        buildConfig true
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't make any difference to me.

Comment: I moved a project to a newer version of AndroidStudio and had the problem with `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`.  Adding `buildConfig true` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Was unable to find a clean solution, so added a workaround:

```
buildConfigField "int", "VERSION_CODE1", String.valueOf(global["versionString"])
```

Comment: How about in KTS?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems fairly easy per this Firebase guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-fastlane

```
lane :increment_version do
  latest_release = firebase_app_distribution_get_latest_release(
    app: "<your Firebase app ID>"
  )
  increment_version_code({ version_code: latest_release[:buildVersion].to_i + 1 })
end
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).